# SonarQube 5.1 too busy due to ElasticSearch

Tags: sonarqube

I have recently migrated from SonarQube 3.7.2 to SonarQube 5.1. Update was successfull and I was able to run analysis.

However now I cannot reach the server and from log it seems ElasticSearch is slowly eating away my disk space.

I tried to restart the server and to delete the data/es directory, but nothing helped.

`sonar.log` is full of these lines:

```
...
2015.05.18 00:00:13 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1431686361188] high disk watermark [10%] exceeded on [Jbz_O0pFRKecav4NT3DWzQ][sonar-1431686361188] free: 5.6gb[3.8%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2015.05.18 00:00:13 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1431686361188] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
...
```

There are just a few Java projects, but two of them are around a couple million lines of code (LOC).

Comment: You should provide more information to help us understanding the issue: JVM information, disk usage, logs, number and typology of projects, ...
Thanks

Comment: Addeda few log entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server does not have enough available disk space to feed its internal Elasticsearch indices.
Note that an external volume can be used by setting the property sonar.path.data (see conf/sonar.properties).